# How to add a system font to LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: linux, fonts, libreoffice

My Linux system is using `Monospace Regular` to display Monospace Text. I would like to try the font in my documents. However when I go through my long list of fonts it is not there. How can I make it available to `LibreOffice`? I am NOT trying to customize the LibreOffice GUI, I would like to include the font so that I can print papers in that font. When I visited `/usr/share/` there were more than a dozen folders beginning with `fonts` and the `fonts` folder was convoluted so I couldn't locate it.

Answer (score 1):

That's not actually a font, it's just a placeholder name that gets replaced by one font which actually is both monospaced and regular (not bold, italic...).

On most Linuxes is probably going to be Bitstream Vera Mono.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have ready the TrueType font file you wish to install.

1. In a terminal, open `nautilus` as root:

   ```shellsession
   $ sudo nautilus
   ```
2. Copy the font file into `/usr/share/fonts`
3. Close the terminal and open LO Writer.

You should see your new font in LO font list.